# Magento1 : How to Set NO Payment Method Required

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, magento-1.9, payment, checkout

I am using magento 1.9.I want to display at checkout that "No Payment method required".How to proceed checkout without Payment Method. Or i have to create custom payment method? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default this functionality not available in Magento. But you can follow the below steps to remove the payment step and customize this as per your need.
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/17/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-payment-method-step/